# New ubuntu install mounting to an old /home drive and partition - can no longer access due to .Private and .ecryptfs

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, home-directory, ecryptfs

did a fresh ubuntu mate install (18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS) on a ssd mounting to a HDD with an old /home partition.

It was first unable to boot in but I was able to make it work by redirecting the mountpoint with fstab.  Now I'm able to boot in but it looks like it's redirecting the symlinks of the default folders to the newest install instead of my old one.  As such, I do not have any access to the files in my old home.

It still contains .ecryptfs and .Private which is clearly holding data as seen in gparted and disks. Something with the install went funny obviously and can no longer access the drive.  I'm using the same username though the desktop/computer name is different.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

I'm considering doing a fresh install with no separate /home and seeing if the drive can be mounted just to access the files and redirect home afterwards.

Comment: If you want to recover the old data, you will need to use ecryptfs tools - see for example [Trying to mount old encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36573/trying-to-mount-old-encrypted-home)

Answer (score 0):

hi @steeldriver that is indeed what i ended up doing.

installed `ecryptfs-utils`

ran code, ran into `/run/usr/999/gvfs: Permission denied`

followed the 2nd answer here [“sudo ecryptfs-recover-private” gives “find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied” after botched (?) upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760642/sudo-ecryptfs-recover-private-gives-find-run-user-1000-gvfs-permission-d)

and ran `umount /run/user/1000/gvfs` then `ecryptfs-recover-private`

which required my old pw then mounted my old home to /tmp

I'll stop answer here as now I am looking to move mount points from /tmp to my new home.

Edit: rebooting automounted drive into functioning as usual again.